# Android Emulator Error SDKCtl multi-touch: Invalid packet signature

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation

I try to run android studio project on Emulator but always got error message

> Emulator: emulator: ERROR: SDKCtl multi-touch: Invalid packet
>   signature 50545448 for packet type 808465440, size 808333615

[image]

Comment: What project are you trying to run? That error could be an error in the project code rather than the Android Emulator itself.